# ¿Como comparar 2 listas en python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, lista

Estoy trabajando en Python 3.4, Tengo 2 listas:

```
lista_1 = ['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '20107-10-04'] # Fechas de un periodo  
lista_2 = [['20107-10-01', campo2, campo3], ['2017-10-03', campo2, campo3], ['2017-10-04', campo2, campo3]] #Datos a analizar
```

Quiero comparar las dos listas para ver si el primer dato (fecha) de cada sub lista de la `lista_2` se encuentra dentro de la `lista_1`.

En caso de no encontrarse en la `lista_2` se debe agregar a `lista_2` una sub lista con la fecha faltante y campo 2 y campo 3 como una cadena vacía; al final ordenar la `lista_2` por fecha de la mas antigua a la más reciente.
`Fecha` es un objeto `DateTime` en ambas listas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción simple es usar diferencia de conjuntos para obtener las fechas que están en la primera lista pero no en la segunda.

Luego basta con usar `list.extend` y `list.sort`:

```
from datetime import datetime

lista_1 = [datetime(2017, 10, 1),
           datetime(2017, 10, 2),
           datetime(2017, 10, 3),
           datetime(2017, 10, 4)] 

lista_2 = [[datetime(2017, 10, 1), "a", "b"],
           [datetime(2017, 10, 3), "a", "b"],
           [datetime(2017, 10, 4), "a", "b"]] 

faltan = ([fecha, "", ""] for fecha in set(lista_1) - set(sub_l[0] for sub_l in lista_2))    
lista_2.extend(faltan)    
lista_2.sort()
```

**Salida:**

```
[[datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 1, 0, 0), 'a', 'b'],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 2, 0, 0), '', ''],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 3, 0, 0), 'a', 'b'],
 [datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 4, 0, 0), 'a', 'b']]
```

Una pequeña explicación:

- `set(sub_l[0] for sub_l in lista_2)` crea un conjunto con los primeros elementos de la segunda lista, es decir, crea un conjunto con las fechas de cada sublista de `lista_2`.
- `set(a) - set(b)` retorna los elementos que están en `a` pero no en `b`.
- `faltan` es un generador que retorna una lista `[fecha, "", ""]` por cada fecha que está en `lista_1` pero no en `lista_2`.
- `lista_2.extend` recorre el generador anterior y añade cada elemento a la lista.
- `list.sort()` ordena la lista.

Comment: muchas gracias ya quedo resuelto

Answer (score 0):

La solución de @FJSevilla es sin duda la más óptima por el uso de los `set`. A titulo informativo agrego la solución usando "comprensión de listas", es mucho menos óptima en cuanto a performance y recursos:

```
lista_1 = ['2017-10-01', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-04']  
lista_2 = [['2017-10-01', '1', '2'], ['2017-10-03', '3', '4'], ['2017-10-04', '5', '6']]

lista_2.extend([[f,'',''] for f in lista_1 if f not in [d[0] for d in lista_2]])
print(lista_2)
```

Salida:

```
[['2017-10-01', '1', '2'], ['2017-10-03', '3', '4'], ['2017-10-04', '5', '6'], ['2017-10-02', '', '']]
```

Explicación:

- Con `[d[0] for d in lista_2]` armamos una lista de `Lista_2` solo con las fechas
- Con `for f in lista_1 if f not in [d[0] for d in lista_2]]` nos quedamos solo con las fechas que no estuvieran en `lista_2`
- Con `[f,'','']` construimos el elemento tal como lo queremos
- Con `lista_2.extend(..)` agregamos todos los elementos faltantes

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Es bueno conocer diferentes formas de resolver un problema.